# How to find if key exists in nested object using lodash

Tags: object, nested, lodash

How to find whether a key exists in nested object using lodash?  I have tried using pick but then it's returning single value only.

Below is the example which I have tried
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/57976/deep-pick-using-lodash-underscore

Using above example from browser console it's working fine,  but from angular app it's not working.

Can someone suggest the way to find if key exists or not.

Comment: How is that different inside angular app?

Comment: It's returning only 1 property not all the properties,  so bit confused what was missing

Comment: Please include input data, expected result, and the code you've tried - See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example
](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score -1):

```
let dataAsObj = _.find(dependsOn, field); // it returns the key of the first element
```